# I have a requirement to make calls to two different end points in a sequence on a given call

Tags: apigee

I am trying to achieve the functionality where i have to call two different backends / target endpoints that have completely different interface in a sequence. Output of one call becomes input to the second one upon an error condition from the first call.

I would like to know how to implement this. I am new to Apigee so details will help me.

Comment: Be sure to check out https://apigee.com/docs and if you have some time you might want to go through the Create and Manage APIs course on Apigee at https://pages.apigee.com/learn-create-and-manage-apis-registration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do a ServiceCallout in the request flow.

Set up your Target as whatever the second server is that you need to talk to in the normal flow. Then create a policy to callout to your first target:

```
<ServiceCallout name="myPolicy">
    <Request clearPayload="false" variable="myRequest"/>
    <Response>myResponse</Response>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <Properties/>
        <URL>http://example.com</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
</ServiceCallout>
```

Note the Response block puts the headers and payload from the response into an object that you can then extract variables from using "myResponse" as the <Source> in the ExtractVariables policy.

Then you can build a new request for your target with the variables you set in the ExtractVariables by using an AssignMessage policy

**Service Callout**
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/call-services-or-apis-using-servicecallout

**ExtractVariables**
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/extract-message-content-using-extractvariables

**AssignMessage**
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/generate-or-modify-messages-using-assignmessage